# Insert all cells in a row that begin with, into a different row but compacted

Tags: excel, vba

I have raw data which has a large number of columns. I want to extract cells in the first row which begin with `Sum_Pop`, for example `Sum_Pop2_3,N,`. I then want to input these strings into a summary sheet in row 4, starting at column 5. Can anybody help me with some VBA code for this problem?

The raw data has roughly 160 columns, and I only want to extract about 10-20 cells. I then want them to input onto the analysis sheet in order, so there are not any gaps between the cells, so it will create headers for yearly increase of population for each row.

I've attempted to use this code:

```
Private Sub ()
    Dim qq As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    For qq = 5 To 25
        For I = 1 To 200
            If Sheets("raw").Range("A" & I) Like "Sum_Pop*" Then
                Sheets("raw").Range("A" & I) = Sheets("analysis").Range("R4C" & qq).Value
            Else:
                Next I
            End If
        Next qq
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: What issues are you encountering with your present code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim ws as Worksheet, LastCol as Long, i as Long, MySel as Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("raw")

With ws
    LastCol= .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 to LastCol
        If .Cells(1, i) Like "Sum_Pop*" Then
            If MySel Is Nothing Then
                Set MySel = .Cells(1, i)
            Else
                Set MySel = Union(MySel, .Cells(1, i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Range("E4")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm doing this same function for 2 sheets though, so I've copied the code twice in different areas of the code, and changed the sheet names or the raw data and the Copy Destination for each. The Second code works fine, however the first code fails to collect all columns, stopping after the first and not continueing along.

Comment: probably the arrangement of columns in the other sheet is different. Is it on the first row? Are the values like "Sum_Pop*"? You can edit all that too. If the answer works for you on one sheet, then it works. You should mark it as answer and adapt for the other sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the help, apologies for my lack of knowledge surrounding this! I got it working with your advice! :)